# Is this too much work for a Gateway to do?

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I'm writing a [Gateway class](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/gateway.html) that wraps access to a web service which provides information about a player's item inventory in a video game. This web service returns a variety of information, however I do not need to use all of it.

The only thing I need to know from the web service is if a given game item is present in the player's inventory. This logic would be simple to implement: I would iterate over the player's items, trying to find a match. However, herein lies my primary concern: is this too much work for a Gateway to do? Would it be better practice to have the Gateway merely extract the list of items, and then handle the checking elsewhere? This would seem silly to me, because my program really only cares about the existence of a particular item and I don't really need a list of every item.

Comment: *Facades* perform an extremely valuable service: they make complex things as simple as possible. It's almost always a good idea to write a facade, and I don't see any reason why an access wrapper shouldn't incorporate it. In fact, it seems like an especially good place to do it.

Comment: It's hard to say what would be best for you with so little information, however, if Gateway is supposed to be a controller, then traditionally, it should be relying on another class to retrieve item information.  The controller, knowing that only the existence is necessary, would respond only true or false.

Comment: @Neil I'm using the term "Gateway" in [the way that Martin Fowler defined it](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/gateway.html). I will clarify that in my original post.

Comment: @user3124380 Then I think what I said still applies.  It is a good habit to "show" as little as possible in an interface.

Comment: @KilianFoth Based on the reading I've done (particularly in _Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture_), it seems that a Gateway is like a Facade, but for a more particular use. With that in mind, would you say that my Gateway should be doing the kind of work that I'm describing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, a gateway class should translate from the interface you have to the interface you want.  If the interface you want is a simple presence check, by all means write it that way.

I would just caution you as the requirements change and the application grows, to not be afraid to reevaluate that decision.  If your gateway class starts looking too large, or like it's forcing too many abstraction layers together, split it into one that retrieves the list and one that filters/searches the list.  Even if you have only one class, these should at least be separate functions.

Comment: Agreed. The only thing I'd add is that the implementation of the Gateway should still keep the actual network request wrapper separate from the part that searches for a specific item. But that can be as simple as two functions in the same file (until, as Karl said, it gets bigger).

Answer (score 2):

Let's go back to good old SOLID principals. Currently, your Gateway is:

- Providing integration with Web Interface AND
- Checking for an item in users inventory.

You broke Single Responsibility principal :) Is it terrible? No, not really, but, trust me, it's much easier to correct it now, while you don't have a large application instead of correcting things like this later.

So, I would do it this way:

```
// Inventory service.
public class InventoryService
{
    private IWebInventoryGateway _gateway;

    // Injecting a dependency here to decouple classes
    public InventoryService(IWebInventoryGateway gateway)
    {

    }

    // Method that does one an only thing! Checking if the item is in the inventory.
    public bool ContainsItems(string item, int playerId) {
        var inventory = _gateway.GetInventory(playerId);

        // do the list checking here...

        return true;
    }
}

// Gateway interface so you could swap your gateways without affecting any other classes. Decoupling here.
public interface IWebInventoryGateway
{
    IEnumerable<string> GetInventory(int playerId);
}
```